# The argument type 'Null' can't be assigned to the parameter type "" in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-test, bloc, dart-null-safety

How can I fix the null value error. i'm using the bloc pattern. Please check the below image.
Thanks in Advance.

[image]

Comment: Maybe you should define your class as `class BlocTime extends Bloc<EventTime, StateTime?> {}` so that it accepts a `null` state?

Comment: Great. I created the answer so that you can close this issue. Happy coding!

Answer (score 2):

Defining the state of your Bloc as nullable should fix your issue:

`StateTime?` instead of `StateTime`

```dart
class BlocTime extends Bloc<EventTime, StateTime?> {}
```